# esx 4 - c7000 - cisco 3020

Tags: vmware-esx, hp, vmware-vsphere, hp-proliant

I have 4 blades with esx 4 installed in a HP c7000 enclosure. They have 6 cisco 3020 for hp switches in the backend.

The plan was to use 2 switches for iSCSI traffic and the other 4 for data traffic.

I am having a problem trunking the switches to our existing environment. The documentation i keep finding online has commands/features that are not available on the 3020 switch.

Does anyone have this setup anywhere? I am looking to do Virtual Switch Tagging (VST) so i can control the machines vlan via the port groups.

The only time any configuration worked for us was when our network team placed the command

switchport native vlan x

this setup only allowed vlan x to pass traffic and only when the port group was in vlan 0.

Ideas?

thanks for any help.

-GD

Answer (score 1):

The 3020 is a very standard L2 Cisco switch, there's nothing too complex about it, you just need to grab a Cisco CCNA or similar person and get them to setup the trunks, shouldn't take them long.